# How to write a large dask array (numpy.ndarray) to a Zarr file leveraging GPUs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dask, cupy, zarr

I am trying to write a large dask array (46 GB with 124 --  370 MB chunks) to a zarr file using dask. If my dask array was named `dask_data`, then a simple `dask_data.to_zarr("my_zarr.zarr")` would work. But from what I understand, this is a synchronous, CPU bound process.

What I would like to do is to use parallelism with much of the work allocated to a Quadro GV100 GPU. I tried to convert the numpy.ndarray to a cupy.ndarray via `dask_data_cupy = dask_data.map_blocks(cupy.asarray)` and write this out to a zarr file, but I receive:
 `ValueError: object __array__ method not producing an array` (and frankly, I do not see a performance boost either).

How could I go about using a GPU to parallelize writing a dask array to a zarr file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> But from what I understand, this is a synchronous, CPU bound process.

This is probably not true, your bottleneck is likely the storage device. In any case, each chunk is written to a separate file, and in parallel across threads and/or processes (depending on your setup). That is the whole point of the design of zarr, that an application can interact with each chunk independently.

You *may* be CPU bound if you choose to use various encodings of compression; however these do not necessarily lend themselves to GPU operation.

In short, unless your data is already generated on the GPU, I would be surprised if transferring it to the GPU for processing before writing it to files is worth the while. If there were a function to directly read/write cupy arrays to zarr, and your were also processing on the GPU, it would be different - but I don't believe there is.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would need to add `dask_data.map_blocks(cupy.asnumpy)` before calling `to_zarr`.

CuPy tries to make sure that the user intended to do a device to host transfer (as these can be expensive). So intentionally raises when `numpy.asarray` is called on a CuPy array (as would happen during this write).